# "An jedem Tag" vs. "Jeden Tag"

Tags: difference, grammatical-case

Ich suche nach einer Antwort auf die Frage, was der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Formen ist. Beispiel:

> An jedem Montag gibt es Fisch.
>
> Jeden Montag gibt es Fisch.

Im Speziellen wären die grammatikalischen Feinheiten interessant, und unter welche Deklinations- und Grammatikregeln diese Unterschiede fallen.

Die einzige Erklärung, die ich bis jetzt gefunden habe, ist, dass „an jedem“ den Zeitpunkt stärker betont und „jeden“ eher allgemein gehalten wird.

Comment: Fisch gibt's normal freitags ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für mich bedeuten beide Formulierungen *exakt dasselbe* - Mit deinem letzten Satz (Stärkere Betonung des Zeitpunkts) bin ich nicht einig. Für mich ist das Eine einfach eine verkürzte Form des Anderen.

Wahrscheinlich auch wegen der Kürze sehe ich auch sehr viel mehr Verwendungen von "Jeden Montag..." (Google findet für *jeden Montag* Faktor 10 mehr Ergebnisse als für *an jedem Montag* , fragt man ngrams, findet man eine rückläufige Verwendung des Letzteren, es kann also sein, dass *an jedem Montag* eher veraltet ist)

Das Konstrukt "Jeden Montag" ist baugleich zu

> Der Zug nach München fährt jede Stunde.

oder

> Jede Minute sterben xxx Menschen im Straßenverkehr.

Da "Montag" aber hier als *Zeitpunkt* und nicht als  *Invervall* verwendet ist (die Woche zwischen den Montagen ergibt für die Aussage keinen rechten Sinn), passt das hier mAn nicht so richtig.

Andere, ähnliche Sätze haben subtilere Unterschiede:

> Der montägliche Fisch, mal wieder

Sagt dasselbe (Jeden Montag gibt es Fisch), konzentriert sich aber auf den Fisch statt auf den Montag und kann u.U. eine Wertung beinhalten.

> Montags gibt es immer Fisch

Sagt im Prinzip auch dasselbe, setzt aber den Schwerpunkt auf den Montag.

Comment: Grammatikalisch ändert sich aber der Kausus? Vgl. "An jedem Wochenende", "jedes Wochenende"

Comment: @MatthiasB Ja - Wenn man die Präposition, die den Dativ fordert, weglässt, fordert ja keiner mehr den Dativ?

Comment: Ich habe nochmal was dazugepackt, was mir noch eingefallen ist.

Answer (score 4):

So I was researching the same matter and found this:

"Jeden Montag" is an adverb of time and in German, like other adverbs, they often use accusative when not in a different context.

Examples:

> Jeden Montag gibt es Fisch.

"Gibt es Fisch" is the main information, so "jeden Montag" is only the adverb of time and therefore in his simple form in accusative as explained.

> An jedem Montag gibt es Fisch.

Here, there is a preposition "an", which needs dative; therefore changing the grammar rule, but the meaning stays the same.

> Jeder Montag ist schön.

Here, "jeder Montag" is the main information as we are describing it, therefore it is the subject and consequently in nominative.

Comment: @IQV I fixed it.